# Special char in Xslt file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, extension-objects

I'm calling a method of my extension object.

Here is my method's signature:

```
public string GetValue(string xPath) { }
```

And here is the place I call it in my `Xslt` file:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="crn:GetValue('courier:_application/base:_entity/loan:_applicant/base:_entity/person:_phones/base:SmartRefOfPhoneeJDvviUx[base:_entity/contact:_isMobile/base:_underlyingValue='true']/base:_entity/contact:_secondaryPrefix/base:_underlyingValue')"/>
```

Because of the part

> **[base:_entity/contact:_isMobile/base:_underlyingValue='true']**

contains **'** chars, I'm getting an error

> "**Expected token ')', found 'true'.  ...isMobile/base:_underlyingValue=' -->true<-- ']/base:_entity/contact:_extensi...**"

I couldn't find an escape char for X-path. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XSLT/XML escape mechanisms i.e.

```
<xsl:value-of select ="crn:GetValue(&quot;courier:_application/base:_entity/loan:_applicant/base:_entity/person:_phones/base:SmartRefOfPhoneeJDvviUx[base:_entity/contact:_isMobile/base:_underlyingValue='true']/base:_entity/contact:_secondaryPrefix/base:_underlyingValue&quot;)"/>
```